# Equation editor for sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there any equation editor web part (or similar) for sharepoint 2010 that I can download (for free or not doesn't matter) and use in content editor web parts?

http://latex-equation-editor.findmysoft.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Equation_Editor

Comment: Not specifically for SharePoint, but this question could have answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433540/embeddable-wysiwyg-equation-editor

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php  - that just generates a .gif based on your equation or do you need something that will actually manipulate the equation, do the calculations etc.?